# How do I extract images from a pdf in c#?

Tags: c#, image, pdf

How do I extract an image from a pdf file, using c#?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/). Here's an [example](http://www.vbforums.com/showpost.php?s=9cd085b76d0321e4c6191efba4e2f417&p=3455355&postcount=3).

Comment: That example is not working for my pdf file.  It is a pdf file created using VeryPDF, not sure if that has any bearing on the code you referenced not working.

Answer (score 1):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used to extract images from PDFs.

Here is a sample that shows how to iterate trough pages and extract all images from each PDF page:

```
static void ExtractImagesFromPdfPages()
{
    string path = "";
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Pages.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pdf.Pages[i].Images.Count; j++)
            {
                string imageName = string.Format("page{0}-image{1}", i, j);
                string imagePath = pdf.Pages[i].Images[j].Save(imageName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The library won't resample images. It will save them exactly the same as in PDF.

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle, vendor of the library.

Comment: Is it possible to just search a specific area in a pdf document to see if there is an image or not? I am looking at the four corners of a pdf file and i need to find which corner has an image.

Comment: It's not possible with Docotic.Pdf. BUT you can use `PdfPage.GetPaintedImages` method to retrieve information about images actually painted on a page. For each image in the returned collection you can retrieve the bounding rectangle. Then you can just check to see if that bounding rectangle intersect given area.

Comment: @Amina please ask new question next time. do not use comments section for new questions.